# How to export mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, apache

```
mysqldump -u censored -'p32dasdA)k+~Ow9' censored > backup.sql
```

The above code results in error bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

I assume it's because the password contains certain characters, but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue. Also, where should I check for the backup after it's complete?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this: `mysqldump -u censored -p censored > backup.sql`

Then enter the password when prompted. The syntax error comes from mysql seeing the '-' and looking for a valid option, when it gets to ')' it knows there is a problem and throws the syntax exception.

Comment: I think that worked! After I entered the password it moved down to a new line. How will I know it worked? I'm not sure where to check for the backup...

Comment: I think the backup file will appear in the directory where you ran the command from. so if you are in ~, it should appear in ~. I think you can also pass a fully qualified path to the command, '\opt\mysql\backups'

Comment: If it works it will return to a new line waiting for a new command, if it fails you will get a message, you could also watch your current directory for the file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to use `-p'` instead of `-'p`, or maybe `-p'p`.  It would also be more secure to not type the password in there but instead use `-p` with no argument and type the password when prompted.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqldump -u user -p password user > mysql.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -u censored -p 'p32dasdA)k+~Ow9' censored > backup.sql
```

or

```
mysqldump -u censored -p '32dasdA)k+~Ow9' censored > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

try this my friend:

```
mysqldump -u user -p 'database_name' > file.sql

user = your username mysql
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The OP is trying to pass in the password, where you have omitted it entirely, assuming that they are able to supply a password interactively on the tty.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
mysqldump dbname -u username -p > backupfilename
```